# ReactJS Demo Site that Runs on Client Side Only

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am getting confused about ReactJS if it can ever run without server side? I would like to find a boilerplate to play around with React code but one that does not require NodeJS host. All demos I have tried so far are all using NodeJS to generate React pages.

For example https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate

What I need is a simple 2-3 pages website that changes views on menu item clicks to experiment with React website.

Comment: Why not just start from [React Tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) if you're so unsure? Most of boilerplate's NodeJS(Webpack) are used to pack the assets, but it is different from server side rendering.

Comment: You sure can. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html#starter-pack provides a kit and a briefing to get you started.